# Вызов функции main, ее прототип и определение

Tags: c, функции, main

Почему вызов функции `main()` отличается от вызова других функций

```
int main()
{
}
```

VS

```
other_function();
```

?

Где находится прототип `main()`?
Как вообще работает данная функция?
Возможно запускать её из другой функции или использовать в цикле?

Comment: Ответьте себе на такой вопрос: вот запускается программа, а как она узнаёт, какой код обрабатывать самым первым?

Answer (score 1):

Функция `main` - *особая* функция, определяющая точку входа программы (по сути, программа представляет собой именно функцию `main`, вызывающую другие функции). Поэтому ее прототип прошит, грубо говоря, в самом компиляторе.

Работает она, как и другие функции, и в принципе, ее можно даже запустить из другой функции или вызвать в цикле (не уверен в том, что говорит стандарт, исхожу из практики...) - вот [пример](https://ideone.com/OUA9Ns):

```
void f()
{
    for(int i = 2; i < 10; ++i)
        main(i,0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    if (argc < 2) 
        f();
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n",argc);
    }
}
```

Делать это я не рекомендовал бы ни в коем случае. Это **особая** функция, и относиться к ней нужно соответственно.

P.S. Кстати, то, что вы написали вначале

```
int main()
{
}
```

это не вызов, это определение функции `main`.

Comment: Прототип main не вшит в компиляторе, как Вы выразились. Если добавите `-pedantic-errors`, то код не соберется, потому что нет объявления main в функции foo. Стандарт C об этом явно говорит "The implementation declares no prototype for this function".

Comment: @Croessmah  Ну, вероятно, я неудачно выразился. Я имел в виду, что нет заголовочного файла с таковым прототипом. Был бы признателен, если бы вы внесли соответствующую поправку в ответ.